# Twilio Record Create Controller, Passing Nil Results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

I have a controller that accepts an SMS from Twilio and creates a new Transaction. My goal is that I'd like to send a text message that has a number as the body, and then accepts the from phone number to match it to an employee record.

app/controllers/twilio_controller.rb

```
    class TwilioController < ApplicationController

      def process_sms
        @city = params[:FromCity].capitalize
        @state = params[:FromState]
          render 'process_sms.xml.erb', :content_type => 'text/xml'
        end

      def create
        phone_number = params[:From][/\d+/]
        employee = Employee.where(phone: phone_number).first
        if employee
          @transaction = Transaction.new(:item_id => params[:Body], :employee_id => employee, :status => true)
          @transaction.save
        end
      end

    end
```

But the problem is that when I send a text, it creates the transaction record, but creates the 'employee_id' field as null. So I don't know if a part of my ruby below is broken, but I believe that :employee_id is passing null to the new object and I'm not sure what is broken about this. I'd be happy to provide any other pieces of code that you'd need... :Body and :From are parameters of Twilio's incoming SMS. I've made sure that I have an employee in the database with the phone number that I'm sending from, including variations with and without a preceding '1'. So my guess is that there's something wrong with my lookup, but I'm just not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing it like this:

```
@transaction = Transaction.new(:item_id => item[:id], :employee_id => employee[:id], :status => item_status)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
employee = Employee.where(phone: phone_number).first
if employee
  @transaction = Transaction.new(:item_id => params[:Body], :employee_id => employee, :status => true)
  @transaction.save
end
```

To

```
if employee = Employee.find_by_phone(phone_number)
  Transaction.create!(item_id: params[:Body], employee_id: employee.id, status: true)
end
```